# run a c++ application under spark cluster

Tags: c++, apache-spark, machine-learning, bigdata

I am working on my school project. there is a video duplication detection application wrote with c++. The application is designed to run on a single machine, and I would like to create a spark cluster and run that application under the cluster. 
Is this possible? difficult?

Comment: https://www.developer-tech.com/news/2015/feb/19/mapreduce-framework-cc-open-sourced-google/

Comment: more detail: it is an visual studio application. I have the source code, and i can build the executable file as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me try to answer your question:

**First, you should figure out that which format the c++ application has?**

**Is it source code or binary executable bin?**

- `source code`

You can implement the algorithm in java/scala, and make the most use of the cluster resouce, make you job much more quick that the single machine version.

**if your time is limited, you can use gcc to compile your c++ source code, and follow the next method.**

- `binary executable bin`

Because java/scala bytecode(.class format) run on the jvm, not compatible with the native code on machine, which is determined by the combination of compiler and operating system.

In the case, the only choice is get a new process to execute the c++ executable bin, and get what you want through inter process communication, such as pipe.

**In a word, you should get a new process on driver node to de-duplicate your data, and use spark engine to do the following parallel computing to accelerate you project.**

and get new process is so easy in scala or java, please refer the doc:
[Process](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html)

Comment: and this answer is the "temporary optimal" choice, and if you have enough time to attempt, feel free to get new frame with expertimental property~

Comment: Thank for your help!. The algorithm of the c++ code is complex, so I don't think rewriting is a good idea.  If I choose to use the bin file, how do I move the computing part to spark, since the computing is in c++ as well.

Comment: you need not move the c++ part to spark, you just need use spark driver(aka.main logic in program) to get a new process to complete your needed computing.